# How to add gesture recognizer to a UIImageview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

In the project, there are an `UIView` myView and an `UIImageView` myImage behinds the myView, views hierarchy:

UIWindow
|-- UIImageView (myImage)
|-- UIView (myView) [whole screen]

Then added a gesture recognizer to myImage in ViewController

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [myImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

But gesture doesn't affect myImage, myImage has `setUserInteractionEnabled:YES`. It will only affect when myImage placed in front of myView, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If it's behind a view it won't receive touches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `UIView` obviously intercept the touches before they can reach the `UIImageView`.

You can either put your `UIImageView` in front of your `UIView`, or disable user interaction on the `UIView` so it does not intercept the touches.

If you need finer grain over catching your touch events, you may either:

- put your `UIView` on top of the `UIImageView` if it has to for design purposes (if it masks the `UIImageView` a bit for example) but make it not catch events (`userInteractionEnabled = NO`), and use a different `UIView` below the `UIImageView` to actually catch the events outside the `UIImageView`
- keep your `UIView` on top of the `UIImageView` and keep it catching events (`userInteractionEnabled = YES`), but filter the events that pass thru it, by subclassing your `UIView` and overriding either the `pointInside:withEvent:` or the `hitTest:withEvent:` method.

For more information **you should really read [the dedicated Apple Programming Guide related to Event Handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)**.

Comment: but myImage has to stay behind myView, is there a way that I can make a detection while touch start and to determine which view is going to affect?

Comment: Yes. As I stated in my answer, turn user interaction off (`userInteractionEnabled = NO`) on the UIView.
If the `UIView` still needs to capture touch events anywhere except where the `UIImageView` lies, you have multiple possibilities: (1) make your `UIView` on top of the `UIImageView` but with `userInteractionEnabled = NO` and put another `UIView` below the `UIImageView` that capture every touch events that haven't been captured by the `UIImageView` or (2) put the `UIView` on top of the `UIImageView`, subclass it & override the `hitTest:withEvent:` or `pointInside:withEvent:` UIView methods

Answer (score 1):

my code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hasLongPressed)];
[press setMinimumPressDuration:0.1f]; //1ms
press.delegate = (id)self;
[self.DGEMLogo addGestureRecognizer:press];
```

two properties are neccessary to do

1.)
add the GestureRecognizer to your UIImageView (self.DGEMLogo)
[self.DGEMLogo addGestureRecognizer:press];

2.)
set your UIImage property Interaction enabled to TRUE

thats all.