# Adding touch to UIImageView is not working

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried to add tap to UIImageView, as below, but it's not working! **_img_compass_text_background** is **UIImageView**

I found another view is covering my view, but most of top view is full transparent, how can I force taps pass through it?

**In other words how can I disable a view from consuming taps?**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationNameTapped)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
_img_compass_text_background.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[_img_compass_text_background addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: how you check this is not call.

Comment: Add breakpoint in locationNameTapped method and check whether it is calling or not.

Comment: Make sure there is no View front of Image view which is intercepting tap event before it reach to UIImageView.

Comment: Is this `_img_compass_text_background == nil`?

Comment: To which class you added locationNameTapped ? it should be same class as passed to initWithTarget: not image. Also try adding tapGestureRecognizer.setNumberOfTouchesRequired = 1

Comment: do you sure that _img_compass_text_background != nil ? We need more code to help you

Comment: @C_X You are right a view with most parts transparent is covering it, but how can I can pass taps through transparent view to this lower view?

Comment: Just set that view userInteractionEnabled=no;

Comment: @C_X I did, it's not working, still top view is eating my clicks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338964/how-to-add-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiimageview

Comment: Image views have user interaction turned off by default. Try `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your `imageView` has another `view` on top ?

In that case, there are many things you could do:

- Add `tapGesture` on the overlapping `view`, and in the target method, check if the tapped point is contained in the `rect` of the `imageView` frame. Use `locationInView` and `CGRectContainsPoint`.
- Use `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` and check if the `imageView` frame contains the point of touch using `containsPoint`.

EDIT:

Add tap gesture to your overlapping view, with target method something like this:

```
- (void) targetMethod:(UITapGestureRecogniser*)gesture{

    CGPoint tapPoint = [gesture locationInView:(the view that contains both the views)];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, tapPoint)){

        //your code

    }

}
```

Comment: Doing the above is going to require some work. If possible, try to keep the frames separate from each others' bounds. If you absolutely need them where they are currently, you will have to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IBOutlet` to link your image :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
```

and named your property without underscore _ and use CamelCase for your property.

This code works for me :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationNameTapped:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    _background.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [_background addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)locationNameTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"image tapped");
}
```

Comment: Isn't the correct method signature this: `-(void)locationNameTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture`? With `@selector(locationNameTapped:)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having too many images set tag for them and addding

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationNameTapped:)];
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        _background.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
         _background.tag = 0;
        [_background addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    }

    - (void)locationNameTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
    {
          if(gesture.view.tag == 0)
        {
                      NSLog(@"image tapped");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

might be some other view is over your `UIImageView` ..in the case just disable user interaction for the upper view so the under lying view will get the touch events

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right how ever there must be some problem of adding UIImageView to its parent view or another view is covering it try this code if another view is over it

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

or check is this added to its parents view properly or not